# Acumatica changing cache name from extension

Tags: acumatica

We currently have a project where we have extended a number of screens. We need to change the cache name of certain Acumatica DACs through their extension. For some of the cases we were able to change the names using translation dictionaries, for example in the case of Vendor. In other cases, for example APInvoice and Lead/Contact in the Vendor screen, we were unable to do so.

Is there a way to change the cache/view names of objects that cannot be changed through translation dictionaries, so that in the Auditing screen and when error messages pop-up on screen during save, the correct object name is displayed?

Comment: One of "bad" solutions is to get Attribute's value via Reflection and change it. But it's not recommended to do something like that.

Comment: can you provide an example using one of the standard screens which you want to change?